# Restrict Users to Only Edit Media Owned by Users in Their Role

Tags: uploads, user-roles, media-library, user-access

I want my users to only be able to edit media that is owned by other users in the same role as them...

So far all of my research online the past two days have resulted in almost nothing useful to me, I can't even find anyone else online who has expressed wanting to do the same thing.

I do know that I can restrict editing/backend viewing of media files manually using the Advanced Access Manager plugin, but I'd prefer to not have to manually adjust access settings for each new uploaded media file. Any ideas? I'm open to any guidance whatsoever. Thanks!

Comment: Making it show only media uploaded by the current author is easy, but what you're asking for is not trivial. The only way I can think of doing it requires quite a bit of effort and would make the media library significantly slower. It also means changing user roles could be a huge problem. Attachments only know their author, they don't have any information about the authors role. What's the problem that you're trying to solve by doing this? The context around why you want this will be super helpful in answering the question

Comment: The site is going to be an intranet site for a business. We've setup roles based on departments (HR, Engineering, Quality, etc) that will have users who will be able to edit specific pages. We do not want users in the engineering role to be able to edit media uploaded by HR users, but we want multiple HR users to be able to edit the same media. We've come across the Advanced Access Manager plugin, which we can manually restrict media to specific roles, but we're hoping for something more automatic, so us admins don't have to adjust settings for every piece of media uploaded.